# Run a .bat file [Powershell Mode] using python code

Tags: python, powershell, batch-file

Proxy.bat file contains

```
@ECHO OFF 1>NUL 2>NUL
powershell -Command $pword = read-host "enter password" -AsSecureString ; $BSTR= 
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword)  ; 
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR) > .tmp.txt & set /p password= 
<.tmp.txt & del .tmp.txt
>NUL set http_proxy=http://%1:%password%@abc.yz.com:80
>NUL set https_proxy=https://%1:%password%@abc.yz.com:80
>NUL set no_proxy=abc.yz.com
```

Python code

```
from subprocess import Popen
import subprocess
def run_batch_file(file_path):
Popen(file_path,creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)

run_batch_file("D:\\gower\\proxy.bat")
```

Password request is not performing. could you please suggest how can I make the script execute with password response.

Comment: There is a superfluous line-break before `<.tmp.txt & del .tmp.txt`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your primary problem - at least as posted - is that you've spread the command that starts with `powershell` across *multiple lines* (without using `cmd.exe`'s line-continuation mechanism, which is a `^` at the end of the line, but only outside of `"..."` strings).

Here's a streamlined version that also obviates the need for a temporary file, via a `for /f` loop (PSv5+ syntax):

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`
powershell -c "[pscredential]::new('unused', (Read-Host 'enter password' -AsSecureString)).GetNetworkCredential().Password"
`) do set "password=%%i"
```

**Note**: Since you're creating the process that runs the batch file and then PowerShell with flag `subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`, the newly created console window will automatically *close* when the batch file finishes, so in order to see the process' output you'll have to redirect it to a file or place a `pause` at the end of the batch file, for instance.